# Horizontal form with inline radio button and textboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal form in bootstrap and I am trying to arrange a radio button with two text fields like so (sorry I can't embed the image):

[image]

However, I can't see to replicate this. I've tried the following (Jade markup):

```
    .col-sm-4
        .form-group
            label.control-label(for='time') Time Range
            .form-inline
                .form-group
                    input(type='radio', id="from", name='time', value='from', data-toggle='radio')
                    label(for="from") From
                .form-group
                    input(type='text', name='first')
                .form-group
                    input(type='text', name='last')
```

Which results in everything being on one line, but the "From" is completely covered up and the two text boxes are back to back with no space. Is this a simple CSS fix, or am I mis-understanding form layouts in Bootstrap 3? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The rendered html is:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="time" class="control-label">Time Range</label>
<div class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="radio" id="from" name="time" value="from" data-toggle="radio">
       <label for="from">From</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="first">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="last">
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the rendered html? Otherwise it looks like you've got form-groups nested in a form-group... that may be causeing an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you want it:

```
<div class="form-inline">
   <label for="time" class="control-label">Time Range</label>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="radio" id="from" name="time" value="from" data-toggle="radio">
       <label class="control-label" for="from">From</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">To</label>
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="last">
   </div>
</div>
```

See [**this demo**](http://www.bootply.com/oZHrjiowe2)

I'm not sure how to translate that into Jade markup--I'll leave that to you :)

**EDITED to add:** This is what an online converter spit out:

```
  .form-inline
      label.control-label(for='time') Time Range
      .form-group
        input#from(type='radio', name='time', value='from', data-toggle='radio')
        label.control-label(for='from') From
      .form-group
        input.form-control(type='text', name='first')
      .form-group
        label.control-label To
        input.form-control(type='text', name='last')
```

Comment: Forked your answer to build it out to look like his example image: http://www.bootply.com/Xxq6Wy3lFT

Comment: Thanks. I was working on a solution for about 10 to 15 minutes, but I guess my head wasn't wrapped around the use of the form-group class correctly. This clarified its use and so I applied it to what I'd already been working on.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks for converting to Jade as well... save me some time :).